# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not able to open settings even after reinstalling gnome-control-center

Tags: gnome, software-center

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS recently and i am trying to change the settings for that i am not able to find it. So i have installed "gnome-control-center" but still i am not able to open it. The strange thing is the settings are opened but not visible to me. It goes behind the screen. The settings screen is not visible to me. See the screenshot:

[image]

When i tried this option, Terminal with verbose, "gnome-control-center -v"
It gave me the below messages on the terminal:

```
    sami@sami-Inspiron-N5110:~$ gnome-control-center -v
    12:28:26.0836                      GLib:    DEBUG: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
    12:28:26.0855         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties)
    12:28:26.0855         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties) → 0x7f9fd0009890) to the storage
    12:28:26.0855         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color)
    12:28:26.0856         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color) → 0x55c6c981aa00) to the storage
    12:28:26.0856          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:26.0856          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:26.0857         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.Shell,/org/gnome/Shell,org.gnome.Shell)
    12:28:26.0857         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.Shell,/org/gnome/Shell,org.gnome.Shell) → 0x55c6c981aa90) to the storage
    12:28:26.0859      diagnostics-cc-panel:    DEBUG: ABRT vanished
    12:28:26.0859          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: SensorProxy vanished
    12:28:26.0859          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: Has no accelerometer
    12:28:26.0897          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: Resetting current config!
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.897: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.897: watch_established: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 1)
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.898: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.898: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.914: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
    (gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:28:26.915: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
    12:28:36.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:36.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:46.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:46.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:56.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:28:56.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:06.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:06.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:16.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:16.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:26.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:26.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:36.0698          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:36.0699          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:46.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:46.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:56.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:29:56.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:16.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:16.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:26.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:26.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:36.0690          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:36.0690          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:46.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:46.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:56.0698          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:30:56.0698          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:16.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:16.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:36.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:36.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:46.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:46.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:56.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:31:56.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:06.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:16.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:16.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:36.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:36.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:46.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:46.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:56.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:32:56.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:06.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:06.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:16.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:16.0692          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:26.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:36.0690          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:36.0690          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:46.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
    12:33:46.0697          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:38:50.0336                    (null):    DEBUG: No extra argument
12:38:56.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:38:56.0689          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:39:06.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:39:06.0693          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:39:16.0695          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
12:39:16.0695          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to -1:-0
(gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:39:23.209: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:39:23.212: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/color/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:39:23.212: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/desktop/interface/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:39:23.219: sync
(gnome-control-center:7000): dconf-DEBUG: 12:39:23.222: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/control-center/" (active: 1, establishing: 0)
12:39:23.0222         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Destroying cached objects
```

Can anybody help me in this regard.

Thanks.